# Exercise 3.F.21 in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

I solved Exercise 3.F.21.
Is my solution ok?
If my solution is ok, I am afraid that my solution contains unnecessary arguments.
Does my solution contain unnecessary arguments?

> Exercise 3.F.21
> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$ with $W^0\subset U^0.$ Prove that $U\subset W$.

> 3.94 **Definition** ***dual space***, $V'$
> The ***dual space*** of $V$, denoted $V'$, is the vector space of all linear functionals on $V$. In other words, $V'=\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{F})$.

> 3.102 **Definition** ***annihilator***, $U^0$
> For $U\subset V$, the ***annihilator*** of $U$, denoted $U^0$, is defined by $$U^0=\{\varphi\in V':\varphi(u)=0\text{ for all }u\in U\}.$$

> 3.106 **Dimension of the annihilator**
> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Then $$\dim U+\dim U^0=\dim V.$$

> My solution:
> Let $W_1:=\{v\in V : \varphi(v)=0\text{ for any }\varphi\in W^0\}$.
> Let $U_1:=\{v\in V : \varphi(v)=0\text{ for any }\varphi\in U^0\}$.
> Then, it is easy to check that $W_1$ and $U_1$ are subspaces of $V$.
> Obviously, $W\subset W_1$ and $U\subset U_1$.
>
> We prove that $W^0=(W_1)^0$:
> Proof:
> Let $\varphi\in W^0$.
> Then, $\varphi(v)=0$ for any $v\in W_1$ by the definition of $W_1$.
> So, $\varphi\in (W_1)^0.$
> Obviously, $(W_1)^0\subset W^0$ since $W\subset W_1.$
>
> By 3.106, $\dim W+\dim W^0=\dim V.$
> By 3.106, $\dim W_1+\dim (W_1)^0=\dim V.$
> So, $\dim W=\dim V-\dim W^0=\dim V-\dim (W_1)^0=\dim W_1.$
> So, $W=W_1.$
>
> Similarly, $U=U_1.$
>
> Obviously, $U_1\subset W_1$ since $W^0\subset U^0$.
> So, $U=U_1\subset W_1=W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks ok without unnecessary arguments.

Let me describe another approach.
Assume there is some $u_1 \in U $ outside $W$. There is a linear function $\psi$ such that $\psi (u_1)=1$ and $\psi(w)=0$ for all $w \in W$. So there is $\psi \in W^0$ outside $U^0$.

Comment: aerile, Thank you very much for your answer.